# Why am I getting NaN back from a variable and not a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is it when I alert either `cont_home_h` or `cont_other_h` I get NaN? But if I alert the variables `wind_h`, `slider_h` or `head_img_h` I get their height. Have I done the calculation wrong? If you need the CSS I will create a demo but I'm hoping you can just see an error in this jQuery. Thanks.

```js
/*no scroll on content when nav is open*/   
        var wind_h = jQuery(window).height();  
        var slider_h  = jQuery(".slider").height();
        var head_img_h = jQuery(".head").height();

        var cont_home_h = wind_h - slider_h;
        var cont_other_h = wind_h - head_img_h;

        var cont_wrapper = jQuery(".page_cont_wrapper");
        var slider = jQuery(".slider");
        var head_img = jQuery(".head");

        if(slider.length && jQuery("#hd_ft_cont").hasClass("open_nav")){
            cont_wrapper.css("height", cont_home_h);
            cont_wrapper.addClass("no_scroll");
        }else{
            cont_wrapper.css("height", "auto");
            cont_wrapper.removeClass("no_scroll");
        }

        if(head_img.length && jQuery("#hd_ft_cont").hasClass("open_nav")){
            cont_wrapper.css("height", cont_other_h);
            cont_wrapper.addClass("no_scroll");
        }else{
            cont_wrapper.css("height", "auto");
            cont_wrapper.removeClass("no_scroll");
        }

        jQuery(window).resize(function(){
            var wind_h = jQuery(window).height();  
            var slider_h  = jQuery(".slider").height();
            var head_img_h = jQuery(".head").height();

            var cont_home_h = wind_h - slider_h;
            var cont_other_h = wind_h - head_img;

            var cont_wrapper = jQuery(".page_cont_wrapper");
            var slider = jQuery(".slider");
            var head_img = jQuery(".head");

            if(slider.length && jQuery("#hd_ft_cont").hasClass("open_nav")){
                cont_wrapper.css("height", cont_home_h);
                cont_wrapper.addClass("no_scroll");
            }else{
                cont_wrapper.css("height", "auto");
                cont_wrapper.removeClass("no_scroll");
            }

            if(head_img.length && jQuery("#hd_ft_cont").hasClass("open_nav")){
                cont_wrapper.css("height", cont_other_h);
                cont_wrapper.addClass("no_scroll");
            }else{
                cont_wrapper.css("height", "auto");
                cont_wrapper.removeClass("no_scroll");
            }
        });
```

Comment: that's way too much code.

Comment: Firstly, we'd need to see this working so we can see what the values actually are at runtime. Secondly, you've duplicated the same code twice. I'd suggest you instead place the logic in a function and call it onload and also onresize.

Comment: maybe cast the values to int before using them to calculate

Comment: @PhilippSander could it be achieved with less?

Comment: @Reece it's just to much code in the question itself. not for the solution

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm quite new to jQuery so I have no idea what you are saying haha. But I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh I see what you mean now I will do that thanks

Answer (score 5):

Didn't run the code, but I'm pretty sure the NaN comes because of the typo in line 6 of your on-resize function

```
var cont_other_h = wind_h - head_img;
```

The variable is called `head_img_h` everywhere else.

Comment: That's amazingly well spotted.

Comment: was it the culprit?

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after I uploaded it and edited it. It did solve it for the if statement that uses it but the other one doesn't work for some reason. I'll look for more typos. Thanks

Comment: Yet another reason to add `'use strict';` to all non-trivial JS code. [More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Comment: Do you use the debugger? If not I strongly recommend giving it a try. All browsers have a decent one built in nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the main problem was that the if statements where overwriting each other. This is what I did to fix it

```js
/*no scroll on content when nav is open*/   
        var wind_h = jQuery(window).height();  
        var slider_h  = jQuery(".slider").height();
        var head_img_h = jQuery(".head").height();

        var cont_home_h = wind_h - slider_h;
        var cont_other_h = wind_h - head_img_h;

        var cont_wrapper = jQuery(".page_cont_wrapper");
        var slider = jQuery(".slider");
        var head_img = jQuery(".head");

        if(slider.length && jQuery("#hd_ft_cont").hasClass("open_nav")){
            cont_wrapper.css("height", cont_home_h);
            cont_wrapper.addClass("no_scroll");
        }else if(slider.length){
            cont_wrapper.css("height", "auto");
            cont_wrapper.removeClass("no_scroll");
        }

        if(head_img.length && jQuery("#hd_ft_cont").hasClass("open_nav")){
            cont_wrapper.css("height", cont_other_h);
            cont_wrapper.addClass("no_scroll");
        }else if(head_img.length){
            cont_wrapper.css("height", "auto");
            cont_wrapper.removeClass("no_scroll");
        }
```

Comment: that's just a bunch of code again. you could at least add a comment where you changed something.